# Trying to find nearest point on a coastline (in Python), but projection is not working as I expect

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, shapely, proximity

I am trying to find the nearest point on a coastline, to a station. However, I cannot get the correct answer. Here is a minimal example with an artificial coast line: the west coast (w_coast) is closer than the south coast, but no matter what projection I use, the program is not taking account of the curvature of the earth, and decides the south coast point (s_coast) is closer.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import haversine
import shapely.geometry

def dist(xy1, xy2):
    latlon1 = (xy1[1], xy1[0])
    latlon2 = (xy2[1], xy2[0])
    return haversine.haversine(latlon1, latlon2)

"""
 Dots show the coast line.
 Due to "compression" in the x dimension,
 station should be closer to w_coast than s_coast,
 despite being closer to s_coast in cartesian space (1.0 to s_coast, 1.1 to w_coast).

-35  w_coast        station
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
-36  corner.........s_coast

     140            141.1
"""

station = (141.1, -35.0)  # (longitude, latitude)
w_coast = (140.0, -35.0)
corner  = (140.0, -36.0)
s_coast = (141.1, -36.0)

print(f"distance from station to s_coast {s_coast} = {dist(station, s_coast)}")
print(f"distance from station to w_coast {w_coast} = {dist(station, w_coast)}")

# crs = "EPSG:4326"   # gets it wrong
# crs = "ESRI:102036" # gets it wrong
crs = "EPSG:3034"   # gets it wrong
# crs = "EPSG:32754"  # gets it wrong

# create a line in shapely and gpd
coast = (w_coast, corner, s_coast)
shp_coast = shapely.geometry.LineString(coast)
shp_lines = [shp_coast]
gpd_lines = gpd.GeoSeries(shp_lines, crs=crs)

# create a point for the station
shp_station = shapely.geometry.Point(station)
gpd_stations = gpd.GeoSeries([shp_station], crs=crs)

# find the nearest point on the coast, to the station (supposedly)
shp_nearest_point = shapely.ops.nearest_points(gpd_lines[0], gpd_stations[0])[0]
nearest_point = (shp_nearest_point.x, shp_nearest_point.y)
print(f"nearest_point = {nearest_point}, distance from station ="
      + f" {dist(station, nearest_point)}")
```

No matter what projection I use, I get this output:

```
distance from station to s_coast (141.1, -36.0) = 111.19508023353306
distance from station to w_coast (140.0, -35.0) = 100.19373876782255
nearest_point = (141.1, -36.0), distance from station = 111.19508023353306
```

I assume I am passing the wrong thing to `shapely.ops.nearest_points`... what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saying `crs = "EPSG:3034"` or `crs = "EPSG:32754"` doesn't make it so. You actually have to [reproject](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) your points/lines.

Also, shapely doesn't take the curvature of the Earth into consideration, it computes the Cartesian distance between two geometries.

So I assumed since your example coordinates are in Australia, that your lon, lats are in GDA94 and used an Aust. continental Albers projection for the distance calcs (adjust for your actual coordinate reference systems):

```
etc...

crs_geog = "EPSG:4283"   # GDA94 geographic
crs_proj = "EPSG:3577"   # GDA94 / Australian Albers

# create a line in shapely and gpd
coast = (w_coast, corner, s_coast)
shp_coast = shapely.geometry.LineString(coast)
shp_lines = [shp_coast]
gpd_lines = gpd.GeoSeries(shp_lines, crs=crs_geog)

# create a point for the station
shp_station = shapely.geometry.Point(station)
gpd_stations = gpd.GeoSeries([shp_station], crs=crs_geog)

# find the nearest point on the coast, to the station (supposedly)
shp_nearest_point = shapely.ops.nearest_points(gpd_lines.to_crs(crs_proj)[0], gpd_stations.to_crs(crs_proj)[0])[0]
shp_nearest_point = gpd.GeoSeries([shp_nearest_point], crs=crs_proj).to_crs(crs_geog)[0]
nearest_point = (shp_nearest_point.x, shp_nearest_point.y)
print(f"nearest_point = {nearest_point}, distance from station ="
      + f" {dist(station, nearest_point)}")
```

Output:

```
distance from station to s_coast (141.1, -36.0) = 111.19508023353306
distance from station to w_coast (140.0, -35.0) = 100.19373876782255
nearest_point = (140.0, -35.00387499077832), distance from station = 100.19229273830848
```

Comment: Thank you, that does what I was trying to do! And yes, it is in Australia :)